# I am writing a program to automate the entire company I work for… but am only getting paid $24k/y when the average salary of my job is $80-$100k/y

Tags: salary

Good evening, my coworker, and I are in a sort of dilemma, where we are being paid roughly $13/h, or around $23k/y, while we write an extensive JS program to automate the entire processing operation for the company we work for.

Our CEO has told us that we will be, "taken care of" after we get the program finished, but we are still actively working as JS developers, and are not getting the pay for it... no benefits, no dental, nothing but a simple $1 raise. Our CEO also has a small history of 'screwing' people over after he gets their worth out of them.

We are debating on bargaining with our upper management for a proper raise, but any advice on our current situation would be wonderful! We really do love programming, but not getting paid for it doesn't pay the bills.

EDIT:
We are based in Florida, were the average developer salary is at least $70,000/y, we were originally hired as logistic specialist, who on average earn around $40k/y but we just had the hurricane come through our city.  Where we work didn't get much damage at all, which should be noted.

Comment: I don't mean any insult when I ask this question, but how is it that the two of you have the skills to automate your entire company with Javascript, yet were making $12/h and got a $1/hr raise just to do this? What were you doing before this project?

Comment: If the pay is so far out of whack, why did you take the job?

Comment: You should include your location as that will have a great influence on what the typical pay is and how people answer your questions

Comment: `Our CEO also has a small history of 'screwing' people over after he gets their worth out of them.` - How is your resume looking?

Comment: please add some personal details: country, how long have you been working in this company, how long have you been a developer, what do you want in life

Comment: @Joe not saying anything about OP or their skill levels, but it's possible the company is on a platform that does a large portion of the actual work for them. IE a shopping platform like Shopfiy. Then OP and his Coworker would just be connecting the steps together to automate it. That JS isn't necessarily hard, and a lot of preformed answers can be found online.

Comment: I have made some edits about more specific information to our situation to the main question

Comment: It's unclear what hurricane you're referring to or why that is relevant to your pay?

Comment: "Our CEO has told us that we will be, "taken care of" after we get the program finished"  that's total bullshit.   Every time anyone has ever said that, it's a lie.

Answer (score 9):

You get paid for exactly what you accept. If you accepted 24,000 per year, then that is what you're worth. If others are being paid 70,000 for the same job, then go there. Why are you there still?

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to The Workplace! Negotiating with someone that has a

> small history of 'screwing' people over after he gets their worth out of them.

is just horrible. More so, it definetly seems that he is going to do the same with you. You should polish up you resume and start applying for new jobs ASAP.